# Count occurrences of unique values from a flat array

Tags: php, arrays, count, unique

I need to count the occurrences of all of the unique values from my array. Here is an example of it:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 6
)
```

I'm looking for a way to sum all from same value:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 4
    [4] => 1
    [6] => 2
)
```

Comment: Do you want to add all the values in the array. Is that you want or count the number of occurences of a value in an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTM: http://www.php.net/array_count_values

ps: assuming that "[5] => 5" is a typo. Otherwise explain more carefully.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add all the values in an array then you can use :

```
$test = array(1,1,1,1,4,6,6);
$test_sum = array_sum($test);
```

If you want to count the number of occurrences of each value in the array then you can use:

```
$test = array(1,1,1,1,4,6,6);
$test_count = array_count_values($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

*This will result the sum for the array dude*

```
$array =array
(
    1 => 4,
    4 => 1,
    5 => 5,
    6 => 2
);

$sum =0;

foreach ($array as $k=>$v):

    $sum = $sum+$v;

endforeach;

echo $sum;
```

*second answer This could be more easy*

```
echo array_sum($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Sum of array without any function we can get.** 

 <?php
 $array =Array(1,1,1,1,4,6,6);
 $add =0;
 for($i =0;$i<count($array);$i++){    
 $add = $add+$array[$i];
 }
 echo $add;
 ?>

 **predefined function using**

 $array =Array(1,1,1,1,4,6,6);
 echo array_sum($array);
```